# Is that good idea to use Hibernate autogenerated names for constraint?

Tags: hibernate, coding-style, liquibase

Hibernate include hashes in auto-generated constraint names and have no any human readable parts.

For example I run `mvn hibernate4:export`:

```
alter table users 
    add constraint FK_iy6c08j4gj1opcg1f3m0iwnv0 
    foreign key (shop_id) 
    references shop (id);
```

If you only know `FK_iy6c08j4gj1opcg1f3m0iwnv0` it is impossible to guess to what tables/columns that constraint related.

I don't know any tooling that find corresponding columns by given constraint name. I always dig with custom vendor specific `INFORMATIONAL` schema querying.

Do I need to use `@ForeignKey` or `@UniqueConstraint`:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "BAR_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = FK_BAR_OF_FOO))

@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID", name = "PERSONS_PK_CONSTRAINT"))
```

if I use LiquiBase or hand made update scripts? I think DBA are smarter at naming than Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I use LiquiBase and I can tell you that autogenerated FK names are the same, because it is not LiquiBase who does this job, instead Hibernate is.

I have an own configuration of LiquiBase into maven, that creates temporal files which I call *autologs* and that contain incremental differences (it is an automated changelog obtained via `mvn resources:resources liquibase:diff`).

I never copy/paste directly the autolog to the changelog, instead I always review it, fix those things I don't like and finally include it into changelog.

This review process that I do manually, checks several points, for example FK names.

Comment: I just at stage of including LiquiBase into project. My understating of DB change management completely coincide with your practice. Thanks for interest to a question!

Comment: If you are interested, I post an entry in my blog describing how do I configure and use LiquiBase. Maybe you will find it of interest. [Here it is](http://malaguna.github.io/blog/2015/06/09/liquifying-your-project/)

Comment: Thanks! I haven't set up own blog but maintain still work in progress [LiquiBase tips](http://tips.defun.work/liquibase.html)